How can I disable a specific optimization in LLVM and measure the performance impact on my code on macOS M1?
I'm currently working on optimizing code performance for my project on macOS M1, and I'm utilizing the LLVM (Low Level Virtual Machine) toolchain for compilation. In this context, I need to disable a specific optimization to assess its impact on my code's performance.
Specifically, I'm looking to disable the optimization related to  "loop unrolling" or "function inlining"]. I suspect that this optimization might be causing performance bottlenecks in certain scenarios, and I want to quantify the difference before and after disabling it.
Could someone provide guidance on how to disable this optimization in LLVM on macOS M1 and how to accurately measure the performance difference?
What I've Tried:
Research: I've extensively searched through LLVM documentation and online forums to find information on disabling specific optimizations, particularly at different optimization levels like -O2 and -O3. However, I haven't found clear instructions tailored to disable particular optimization.
Experimentation: I've attempted to modify compiler flags or configuration files to disable particular optimizations at both -O2 and -O3 levels using LLVM's optimizer tool. While I've managed to disable some optimizations at these levels, I'm unsure if I'm targeting the correct optimizations or if my changes are having the desired effect on my code's performance.
Performance Profiling: I've used performance profiling tools like Instruments on macOS to measure the performance of my code before and after attempting to disable specific optimizations at -O2 and -O3 levels. However, I'm not entirely confident in the accuracy of my measurements, and I'm seeking guidance on best practices for performance measurement on the Apple M1 chip.
Expectations:
I'm looking for expert guidance on the specific steps I need to take to disable particular optimizations at different levels (-O2 and -O3) in LLVM on macOS M1 using the LLVM optimizer tool. Specifically, I need instructions on targeting and disabling individual optimizations while leaving others intact. Additionally, I need guidance on accurately measuring the performance impact of these changes using performance profiling tools like Instruments. Any insights or best practices related to optimizing code for the Apple M1 chip would be highly valuable.

Loop unrolling and function inlining are two totally different things that are not even remotely related (well, except under the general category of being optimizations). You mention profiling, but has that profiling identified either of these areas of your code specifically as being a bottleneck? With today's compilers, it's highly unlikely that you're experiencing an issue in either of these areas, and the time you've spent looking into it at all could probably have been spent much more productively.

There is the loop-unroll and inline compilation pass in LLVM but I guess you do not really use LLVM but Clang which is different. See: https://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html
